# Is there SWT Combo Box with any Object as data and LabelProvider for display?

Tags: java, combobox, swt, eclipse-rcp

I'm searching for an implementation of a Combo Box in SWT that will allow me to set the the entries in it with a list of any Object, in a similar way to Trees and Tables.

Ideally I want the String when dropped down to be able to be different to the final String once selected. IE a drop down to select a person that shows their age next to their name in the list, but only their name when selected and placed in the box.

All I can find that exists are String based Combo Boxes with no way of describing different display options, so I guess i's going to have to build a new component if I want the thing to work, but I was hoping someone has already implemented such a thing (since I've seen this sort of functionality in some applications) and I just can't find it?

I hope to create something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The JFace [`ComboViewer`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ComboViewer.html) seems to be what you want. It is backed by a `ModelProvider` which holds your Objects. A [`LabelProvider`](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/LabelProvider.html) is used to display the text inside the combo.

[Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJFace/article.html#jfaceviewer_combo) is an excellent tutorial by Vogella.

Here is an example that does what you want. It basically saves the current combo selection if a boolean of the displayed objects:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final ComboViewer viewer = new ComboViewer(shell, SWT.READ_ONLY);

    viewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());

    /* if the current person is selected, show text */
    viewer.setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider() {
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element) {
            if (element instanceof Person) {
                Person current = (Person) element;

                if(current.isSelected())
                    return current.getName();
                else
                    return "";
            }
            return super.getText(element);
        }
    });

    final Person[] persons = new Person[] { new Person("Baz"),
            new Person("BazBaz"), new Person("BazBazBaz") };

    viewer.setInput(persons);

    /* within the selection event, tell the object it was selected */
    viewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
            IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) event.getSelection();
            Person person = (Person)selection.getFirstElement();

            for(Person p : persons)
                p.setSelected(false);

            person.setSelected(true);

            viewer.refresh();
        }
    });

    viewer.setSelection(new StructuredSelection(viewer.getElementAt(0)), true);

    shell.pack();
    shell.setSize(200, shell.getSize().y);
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}

public static class Person {
    private String name;

    /* this will be true for the selected person */
    boolean isSelected;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.setSelected(false);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean isSelected) {
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks I had hoped there'd be a viewer for this but couldn't find it for some reason, it doesn't seem to allow for different Strings though I suppose I'll just have to accept that as it's not worth building a new component for.

Comment: @GlenLamb What do you mean by _different strings_?

Comment: As in my question, I would like to have more details in the list about the object. Specifically in my situation I have accounts with a sort code and would like to show the sort code in the list but not in the text box.

Comment: @GlenLamb So you want the _selected text_ to be different from the _unselected text_?

Comment: @GlenLamb Ok,then you will have to do that yourself in the `getText` method of the `LabelProvider`.

Comment: I've added a (bad) mock to my question. The idea is that the drop down will show a different string created from the objects, and selection of one box will update the others. (the update part is just outside the scope of my question)

Comment: @GlenLamb See my comment above. You can define the `String` that is shown yourself by using the `getText` method.

Comment: @GlenLamb Well, sure. Just compute the text that should be shown and return it. The method is called every time the viewer will display your items. So you can determine which string to show.

Comment: Sure I guess If I know if it's part of the list or not that will work

Comment: Sorry that was a question, can I tell from the label provider whether the list or the box is asking for the label?

Comment: @GlenLamb Added a working example. Should be a good starting point for you.

Comment: Yeah I thought about doing it that way, but that is still a little hinky as the current selection in the list looks different to all the others, not too terrible but I was hoping for a sure-fire way to know where the label being asked for would end up. Thanks for your help. I'll accept you answer. *grudgingly* :-)

Comment: added in some debug, and it looks like there's no way to do it without the anomaly in the selected item because it doesn't re-request labels on drop down.

Comment: @GlenLamb Yeah, realised that during testing. You can force the viewer to re-request the labels with `viewer.refresh()`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've done but that means there is definitely no way to have the same element showing 2 different labels at once. So i've gone with your idea.

Answer (score 5):

Many thanks to Baz for putting me on the right track and providing me with some initial code. But having taken all this in I wanted something cleaner to use in my RCP view itself and also though a generic instance of a combo box would be a nice to have in future, so I've wrapped all the boilerplate stuff in a new class that you can use like this:

```
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
    persons.add(new Person("Baz",26));
    persons.add(new Person("Glen",27));
    persons.add(new Person("Jimmy",18));

    TypedComboBox<Person> box = new TypedComboBox<Person>(parent);

    box.addSelectionListener(new TypedComboBoxSelectionListener<Person>() {

        @Override
        public void selectionChanged(TypedComboBox<Person> typedComboBox,
                Person newSelection) {
            System.out.println(newSelection);
        }
    });

    box.setLabelProvider(new TypedComboBoxLabelProvider<Person>() {

        @Override
        public String getSelectedLabel(Person element) {
            return element.getName();
        }

        @Override
        public String getListLabel(Person element) {
            return element.getName() + " | " + element.getAge();
        }
    });


    box.setContent(persons);

    box.selectFirstItem();
```

For my view where I'm going to need multiple selection boxes with various objects I am much more happy using the typed box as I'm not casting stuff and reproducing boilerplate code in the body of the view's code.

You don't have to set a label provider if you just want the toSting() method used, otherwise there are two labels to provide, one for the selected item, and one for all the others.

Just in case anyone stumbles upon this question with the same issue as me here's my code, feedback would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ArrayContentProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ComboViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelectionChangedListener;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IStructuredSelection;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.LabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.SelectionChangedEvent;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredSelection;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class TypedComboBox<T> {

    private ComboViewer viewer;
    private TypedComboBoxLabelProvider<T> labelProvider;
    private List<T> content;
    private List<TypedComboBoxSelectionListener<T>> selectionListeners;
    private T currentSelection;

    public TypedComboBox(Composite parent) {
        this.viewer = new ComboViewer(parent, SWT.READ_ONLY);
        this.viewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());

        viewer.setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider() {
            @Override
            public String getText(Object element) {
                T typedElement = getTypedObject(element);
                if (labelProvider != null && typedElement != null) {
                    if (typedElement == currentSelection) {
                        return labelProvider.getSelectedLabel(typedElement);
                    } else {
                        return labelProvider.getListLabel(typedElement);
                    }

                } else {
                    return element.toString();
                }
            }
        });

        viewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
                IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) event
                        .getSelection();
                T typedSelection = getTypedObject(selection.getFirstElement());
                if (typedSelection != null) {
                    currentSelection = typedSelection;
                    viewer.refresh();
                    notifySelectionListeners(typedSelection);
                }

            }
        });

        this.content = new ArrayList<T>();
        this.selectionListeners = new ArrayList<TypedComboBoxSelectionListener<T>>();
    }

    public void setLabelProvider(TypedComboBoxLabelProvider<T> labelProvider) {
        this.labelProvider = labelProvider;
    }

    public void setContent(List<T> content) {
        this.content = content;
        this.viewer.setInput(content.toArray());
    }

    public T getSelection() {
        return currentSelection;
    }

    public void setSelection(T selection) {
        if (content.contains(selection)) {
            viewer.setSelection(new StructuredSelection(selection), true);
        }
    }

    public void selectFirstItem() {
        if (content.size()>0) {
            setSelection(content.get(0));
        }
    }
    public void addSelectionListener(TypedComboBoxSelectionListener<T> listener) {
        this.selectionListeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeSelectionListener(
            TypedComboBoxSelectionListener<T> listener) {
        this.selectionListeners.remove(listener);
    }

    private T getTypedObject(Object o) {
        if (content.contains(o)) {
            return content.get(content.indexOf(o));
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void notifySelectionListeners(T newSelection) {
        for (TypedComboBoxSelectionListener<T> listener : selectionListeners) {
            listener.selectionChanged(this, newSelection);
        }
    }
```

And the label provider interface.

```
public interface TypedComboBoxLabelProvider<T> {

    public String getSelectedLabel(T element);

    public String getListLabel(T element);

}
```

And the selection listener:

```
public interface TypedComboBoxSelectionListener<T> {

    public void selectionChanged(TypedComboBox<T> typedComboBox, T newSelection);
}
```